# Date format Mapping to JSON Jackson Not working properly

Tags: jersey, jackson

I have a Date format coming from API like this:`"date": 1498729813872`

But actually i want in `dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss` in this way

i am using jersey and jackon for data serialising how can i change date in seconds for mat to specific format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable serializing dates as timestamps on Jackson's `ObjectMapper`. E.g.

```
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Annotate the date field appropriately. E.g.

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
private Date date;
```

or also set the format on the `ObjectMapper`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
mapper.setDateFormat(df);
```

[Docs for JsonFormat](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html)

Comment: `JsonFormat.Shape` refers to content of the resulting JSON not the Java object you serializing. There is no JSON spec for representing dates. The `Shape` can be `STRING` or `NUMBER` in your case. I added documentation link for `JsonFormat`

Comment: how can i add time zone .. i am storing as ist and it converting to GMT when serialising